# AxoCover Run Test Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: unit-testing

I'm wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to run tests with AxoCover from code, like Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.